# How to deploy .war file successfully in tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat7, war, web-deployment

I deployed a web application .war file in tomcat 8.0. But when i run start the server startup.bat and access url "localhost:8080/application" it loads an incomplete web application page. I deployed a spring boot a[llication .war file. And its running smoothly in spring framework.

Comment: Please provide your build.gradle or pom.xml

Comment: Please also provide war file name, and check `/logs/catalina.out`.